# Ignore Null Field when printing name, middle I., and last name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, printing

Using Word in a multi-print document, I would like to ignore null fields when printing. As it is now, things are fine when a filled middle initial is present, but if no middle initial is present, it prints an extra space between first and last name. I'm drawing data from an excel spreadsheet. My word document has the correct spaces in the document. Should those be changed in some way? Thank you.

Comment: place the field without a space character and then use a conditional on the merge field to add the extra space only when needed. In this case (pseudocode), `{FIRST}{IFMIDDLEthenSPACE}{IFMIDDLEthenMIDDLE} {LAST}` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-the-rules-for-a-mail-merge-d546ee7e-ab7a-4d6d-b488-41f9e4bd1409